# How to directly show the Maven directory in Intellij Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image]
[image]

Here is the Maven project structure in Intellij Idea, it should be clicked one by one to unfold, how to show the Maven directory like in Eclipse as shown above.

**I have selected the `Flatten Packages` option.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the gear icon in the `Project Files` view and select `Flatten Packages`.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Note: you must be in the **Project Files** view not in the **Project** view. See this screenshot:

[image]

More details [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-tool-window.html).

Comment: It does not work, I have selected the Flatten Packages option. Please see hte udpated question.

Comment: @JohnChou I've updated the answer to reiterate that you must be in the **Project Files** view not the **Project** view.

Comment: Thx it's ok, but it seems more strange.